# To check if string is palindrome using recursion?

Tags: java, string

There is something wrong with my code as one the testcase in my assignment is coming out wrong, giving me runtime error when I submit the code online. That testcase could be any String. I believe that everything is fine with the code as I have checked it manually for many testcases.

**HERE IS THE CODE**

```
public static boolean isStringPalindrome(String input) {
    if(input.length()==0 || input.length()==1)
        return true;

    int first = 0;
    int last = input.length()-1;

    if(input.charAt(first) != input.charAt(last))
        return false;

    String str="";
    for(int i=first+1;i<last;i++){
        str = str+input.charAt(i); 
    }
    boolean sa = isStringPalindrome(str);
    return sa; 
}
```

**Sample Input**

```
racecar
```

**Output**

```
true
```

**Sample Input**

```
pablo
```

**Output**

```
false
```

Comment: you are getting runtime error? I am surprised! can you post what is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: @WasiAhmad the online tool doesn't tell that it just displays the simple msg `runtime error(NZEC)`

Comment: I have updated my answer, I didn't find any problem in your code except a `null` string check. You can try by adding that condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler way to check for palindrome can be:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s)
{   if (input == null)
        return false;
    else if(s.length() == 0 || s.length() == 1)
        return true;

    /* check for first and last char of String:
     * if they are same then do the same thing for a substring
     * with first and last char removed. and carry on this
     * until you string completes or condition fails.
     */
    if(s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(s.length()-1))
        return isPalindrome(s.substring(1, s.length()-1));

    return false;
}
```

**Update**

You are getting `runtime error(NZEC)` which means `non-zero exit code`. It means your program is ending unexpectedly. I don't see any reason except that your program doesn't have a `null` check. Otherwise, I have gone through your code carefully, you are doing the same thing which I have suggested.

Comment: I am also doing that but somehow my code is not working for a single testcase and I don't know what case that could be?

Comment: did you find any test case for which your code is not working?

Comment: no i didn't find any testcase although checked for many different testcases and all seem working fine

Answer (score 3):

Your code appears to be overly complicated for recursively testing if the `String` is a palindrome. Something like,

```
public static boolean isStringPalindrome(String input) {
    if (input == null) {
        return false;
    } else if (input.isEmpty() || input.length() == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    int len = input.length() - 1;
    return input.charAt(0) == input.charAt(len) //
            && isStringPalindrome(input.substring(1, len));
}
```

Is recursive without embedding a `for` loop. Because if you can do that, you should do something like

```
public static boolean isStringPalindrome(String input) {
    if (input == null) {
        return false;
    } else if (input.isEmpty() || input.length() == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    int len = input.length();
    for (int i = 0; i <= len / 2; i++) {
        if (input.charAt(i) != input.charAt(len - 1 - i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick help but I can't find out what is wrong with my code as my logic is same as yours.

Comment: @PrinceVijayPratap Your code is lacking the `null` guard, that might be what the test-case is testing for.

Comment: @JornVernee ok wait i'll try that